# Numpy setting every column in a matrix to a certain value matching a condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix D and sort every row with the indicies (argsort). I'm trying to set values of some_matrix at indicies 1-5 in np.argsort(D) to 1. What I have below does what I need, but is there a way to do this in one line with numpy arrays?

```
some_matrix = np.zeros((n,n))

for i in range(n):
    some_matrix[i,np.argsort(D)[i,1:5]] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that you don't need a full sort, only a partition of elements 1-4 (I assume you need elements 1,2,3,4, because that's what your code does). So let's use that:

```
#assuming you want indices 1,2,3,4 of the sorted array, in any order
indices = np.argpartition(D, (1, 4), axis=1)[:, 1:5]
```

Now we've got indices of `D` with the first, second, third and fourth smallest elements (this is similar to `indices = np.argsort(D, 1)[:, 1:5]`, but will be faster for large arrays). All we need is to set these elements to `1`

```
np.put_along_axis(some_matrix, indices, 1, axis=1)
```

Comment: I think you could get the indices directly with one ```argpartition``` by specifying ```kth = [1,2,3,4]```?

Comment: @Kevin indeed, thanks. I've edited the answer (though I've used `(1, 4)` because it might be marginally faster).